# CommandName = Insert in EditTemplate of ASP.NET ListView throws "Insert can only be called on an insert item"

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am supporting a web application. In that, there are two tables - TaxCode and TaxRate. TaxCode has 1 to many relationship with TaxRate.

The UI has a ListView with LayoutTemplate, ItemTemplate and EditTemplate to show TaxCode. When the users selects a tax code in EditTemplate it shows a CutomGridView that allows the user to create or edit tax rates for that particular tax code. This CustomGridView has 3 rows each has 4 template fields as shown below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="highlightTitlebar" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-Height="30px">
<HeaderTemplate>
  <custom:CustomImageButton ID="imgAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="image/add_round.gif" OnClick="imgAddTaxRateDetail_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
   <custom:CustomImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="image/edit.gif"  CommandName="Edit" />
</ItemTemplate>          
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgUpdate" runat="server" ImageUrl="image/update.gif" CommandName="Update" />
   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfId" Value='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgInsert" runat="server" ImageUrl="image/insert.gif" CommandName="Insert" OnClick="imgInsert_Click" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

Each row in the CustomGridView is a template field. In, below image EffectiveOn section is CustomGridView,

[image: How the CustomGridView is binded with ListView]

When I try to save TaxRate with proper EffectiveOn and Rate, it throws "Insert can only be called on an insert item. Ensure only the InsertTemplate has a button with CommandName=Insert." error as the ListView doesn't have InsertTemplate. But the record gets inserted into the DB.

Please let me know if there is any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.
Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.insertitemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

So you can do either of these things.

1. Create an InsertItemplate and insert using the ItemInserted event of the listview
2. Change the CommandName to CommandName="InsertData" and catch that event on the ItemCommand

Comment: I do not see any document on MSDN for InsertData command. There is "Insert" though.